# android - notification not showing android api 23 and above

Tags: android, android-notifications

This is my code for showing notifications, it's working on `Android` below `API` level 23 but it's not working on `API` level 23+.

```
CharSequence contentText = msg;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("msg",msg);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

b.setAutoCancel(true)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText(contentText)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setContentInfo("Info");

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Random rd = new Random();
notificationManager.notify(rd.nextInt(75), b.build());

private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.ic_launcher2 : R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
}
```

I've made white icon for launcher .

What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it'w not working" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare , thanks for reply , it means that it doesn't show any notifications